# Задача по функциям C++

Tags: c++

Оформить функцию поиска номера максимального элемента массива среди отрицательных элементов, В главной программе Дано 3 одномерных массива a,b,c длиной 30 элементов каждый. применить функцию для каждого из 3-х заданных массивов. найти произведение найденных номеров максимальных элементов. (в функции не должно быть операторов ввода или вывода)

почему не работает максимальное отрицательное число?

```
#include "iostream"
#include "ctime"
#include "cstdlib"
using namespace std;

int s(int a[], int n)
{
int s=0;
int a_max=0;
for(int i=0;i > n;i++)
{
if (i < 0 && i < a_max)
a_max=i;
}
return a_max;
}

int main(){
const int n=30;

int a[n],b[n],c[n];
srand(time(NULL));
for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
cout<<(a[i]=rand()% 100 - 50)<<' ';
cout<< endl;
for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
cout<<(b[i]=rand()% 100 - 50)<<' ';
cout<< endl;
for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
cout<<(c[i]=rand()% 100 - 50)<<' ';
cout<< endl;
cout << "1---\t" << s(a,n) << endl << "2---\t" << s(b,n) << endl << "3---\t" << s(c,n) << endl;
}
```

вывод:

```
-1 29 29 -16 7 9 -37 30 -18 40 -47 3 -48 -10 44 35 22 34 -33 -11 -11 -18 41 -12 27 -40 39 3 -15 -39
-15 20 -30 -7 48 18 -1 11 33 -21 -48 -34 7 -37 -39 44 30 -30 -20 14 31 20 -6 37 10 -25 17 35 -41 -8
-11 12 12 -22 -11 -37 47 -33 16 0 40 -23 -33 -24 48 -28 -11 7 32 40 -46 -32 -41 26 40 -27 21 6 -9 17
1---    0
2---    0
3---    0
```

Comment: Вот интересно - нафига Вы в `s` передаёте `a[]`, если ни разу его там не используете...

Comment: потому что, если я буду передавать  только один аргумент, то выдает ошибку,также выдает ошибку при отсутствии аргументов, уже 2 дня мучаюсь над этой задачей и нифига толкого не приходи, уже самого это раздражает, а выбора у меня особого нет, да еще одну задачу решать, так как зачетка мне нужна. бросать учебу не охото из-за того что плохо понимаю C++

Comment: Лучше использовать `<random>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

У вас совершенно не верно реализована функция поиска максимума среди отрицательных.

1. Начальная инициализация это первый отрицательный элемент. Его нужно найти.
2. Далее обычный поиск максимума
   Определенная проблема есть с тем, что в массиве может не быть отрицательного элемента, тогда его номер принимаем за -1

   ```
   int numOfMax(int a[], int n)
   {
      int n_max=-1;

      for(int i=0; i < n;i++)
       {
         if (a[i] < 0 ){
          if (n_max==-1){n_max=i;}
          else{
              if (a[i]>a[n_max]){ n_max=i;}
          }
        }

   }
   return n_max;
   }



   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
   const int n=30;
   int a[n],b[n],c[n];
   srand(time(NULL));
   for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
   cout<<(a[i]=rand()% 100 - 50)<<' ';
   cout<< endl;
   for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
   cout<<(b[i]=rand()% 100 - 50)<<' ';
   cout<< endl;
   for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
   cout<<(c[i]=rand()% 100 - 50)<<' ';
   cout<< endl;

   cout << numOfMax(a,n)*numOfMax(b,n)*numOfMax(c,n);

   }
   ```

Comment: нормально ли что вывод положительный?

Comment: А какой должен быть? Номер элемента это 0,1,2. и т.д. Вы путаете номер и значение элемента. a[2]=-100. 2 это номер, 100 значение. У вас в задаче произведение номеров наибольших отрицательных.

Comment: По моему ваш код не выполнит то, что нужно. Потестируйте, проверьте...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan это стандартный алгоритм поиска максимума по условию. Обратите внимание, что функция ищет не значение максимума, а номер элемента с таким значением.

Comment: becouse, я понимаю что функция ищет индекс,  но  if (a[i] < 0 ) (для отрицательных чисел всегда выполнится) и if (n_max==-1){n_max=i;  вызывают сомнения, а самому неохота вдобаваться в подробности

Comment: @ARHovsepyan n_max=-1 это значит, что мы не видели до этого отрицательного числа и сейчас можно сделать начальную инициализацию номером первого отрицательного числа. Собственно это примитивная вещь, не понятно почему возникают вопросы. Подумайте, разберитесь, это не сложно.